# (network.c.379) can't bind to port: 80 Address already in use

Tags: lighttpd, ips

I have one server running both apache and lighttpd on two separate IPs. After rebooting the server I can't access the stuff on lighttpd:

/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart
(network.c.379) can't bind to port:  80 Address already in use

Comment: It seems you running apache and lighttpd both on port 80? in lighthttpd conf file change port to different from 80. Port 80 is in use by apache.

Answer (score 5):

do a `netstat -pntle  | grep :80` to see which process is running on this port. If it is apache, you need to configure it to listen only on one IP.

Comment: netstat -pntle | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      0          88899      10103/lighttpd

########

Does this mean lighttpd is already running on port 80? I might be lying to you and there is no apache on this box at all (sorry my admin is away for the moment).
------------------

Comment: You are right, your lighty is on this port. After if it doesn't work, check the logs to see what's append